# how to test with parameterized regex (e.g. /${user}/) on puppet?

Tags: regex, puppet

I need to get a user's home directory. I decided to get it with parsing a ::getent_passwd string (which is a custom fact build as
 concatenation of the contents of the `/etc/passwd`)
 and extract the relevant information with the help of the regex.

When I test the `::getent` with fixed string ("`adam`"), extraction works:

```
if "$::getent_passwd" =~ /\|adam:x:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]*:([^:]*):/ {
  $user_home = $1
  notify{"This works":}
}
```

But when I build a regex with the `$user` variable, nothing gets matched:

```
if "$::getent_passwd" =~ /\|${user}:x:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]*:([^:]*):/ {
  $user_home = $1
} else {
  fail{"this fails":}
}
```

Client and server use Puppet 3.7.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Puppetserver uses puppetdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer five years later, but now there's an easy way.
For others landing here... Try the [regexp constructor](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/function.html#conversion-to-a-regexp) to build a regexp from a string :

```
if("abcd" =~ Regexp("${myvar}") { (...) }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems, using normal variables in puppet regex is not possible:
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#regular-expressions
https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4155

There is workaround proposed in the link above :

> regex.erb:

```
<% if /(^|\s+)#{string2}(\s+|$)/.match(string1) then %>yes<% else %>no<% end %>
```

> manifest:

```
$testre = template('regex.erb')
if $testre == "yes\n" { notify{"success!": } }
```

Comment: Thank you. It really took me by surprise. Need for walkarounds for such basic and ubiquitous functionality cast shadow over the language.

Comment: Puppet 4 will be less cumbersome in this regard, or so I hear.